# Openfeint: Batch requests to openfeint servers (get achievements, unlock achievements, submit scores)

Tags: android, ios, openfeint

I have a scenario where I would like to send out multiple requests to Openfeint servers to unlock several achievements at the same time. From the API, it seems like I am only able to unlock only one achievement with one request to Openfeint's server. Does this mean i have to shoot off multiple requests if I would like to unlock more than one achievements?

Also, how can I get a list of achievements that the User has already earned?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) As far as I know, yes, you need to unlock them one by one. If you write a function for it, it'll be only one line of code per achievement.

2) You can easily do that with Dashboard. Dashboard holds the achievements, leaderboards, profile pages, etc.

```
// Open OpenFeint Achievements
Dashboard.openAchievements();
```

Edit: I probably misunderstod you. I don't want to give you a stupid answer, but I would do the following:
-I'd store all of my achievements ID in an Array
-I'd check if they are unlocked or not by this way:

```
Achievement aAchievement = new Achievement(ID);
if (aAchievement.isUnlocked){
 ...
} else {
 ...
}
```